# How to throw type error before applying merge pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is feature request question, Please let me know Am I the only one doing these kind of problem, If so, help me how you guys are avoiding this error, or else I will request to make this feature.

One of the basic operation in pandas is `merge`. Any how while performing merge operation, even though data is same but `dtype` has different, it won't merge. one of my frequent mistake in `pd.merge` I faced was **applying pd.merge without checking their dtype**. I'm wondering is there any way `pandas` help me to find out it's dtype and **raise user warning** if dtype of key column is not same. Anyway there is no meaning of applying merge operation where the dtype of columns are not same.

Please let me know what you guys thinking about this problem? or how elegantly solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the dtypes of each column directly

```
if len(df1.columns) != len(df2.columns):
    raise ValueError('Column number mismatch')

for col1, col2 in zip(sorted(df1.columns), sorted(df2.columns)):
    if col1 != col2:
        raise ValueError('Column name mismatch')
    if df1[col1].dtype != df2[col2].dtype:
        raise ValueError('Column dtype mismatch')
```

Comment: It check dtype for both df's all columns. I'm looking for generic snippet to handle both `left_on`,`right_on`and `on`.